# Javascript memory game puzzle

Tags: javascript

I am coding a memory game that allows an alert to flash up with a 5-6 digit code that you have to then remember and place into a prompt box. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var mathRandom = (Math.round(Math.random()*10000))

alert(mathRandom);

var answer=prompt("What is the number?");
if(answer === mathRandom)
    {
        alert("Well done")
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Wrong")
    }
```

The problem with my code is that even when you get it right the alert says wrong, I think this is because when I am checking if the variables are equal the mathrandom generates a new number. I was wondering if I could have some help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `answer` is a string and `mathRandom` is a number. You are using `===` which doesn't coerce types. You need to convert your `answer` to a number and then compare:

```
if (+answer === mathRandom) {
    alert("Well Done");
}
```

Or:

```
if (parseInt(answer) === mathRandom) {
    alert("Well Done");
}
```

Or you could just use the `==` operator:

```
if (answer == mathRandom) {
    alert("Well Done");
}
```

Which will automatically convert the number in `mathRandom` to a string.

Also see this question: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

To better understand the difference between `==` and `===`

Comment: @WTFreezer please accept the answer if solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

`===` checks both the value and the type of the variable. Math functions generate number, while prompt generates string. This is why the variables are always unequal.

Replace that with `==` which checks only values - and your code will work.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bx7W8/**

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the result of the prompt to a number. Right now you're doing a comparison with a string and a number.

In JavaScript:

```
750 !== "750";
750 === parseInt("750", 10);
```

Here's the fix:

```
var mathRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

alert(mathRandom);

var answer = parseInt(prompt("What is the number?"), 10);
if (answer === mathRandom)
{
    alert("Well done")
}
else
{
    alert("Wrong")
}
```